# Parse a char from an xml in C language?

Tags: c, xml, parsing, scanf

I'm passing as input to my program: `"<param value=s/>"`

I use this code:

```
char character[1];
sscanf(data, "<param value=%c/>", &character);
printf("%c", character);
```

However the output seems to be "s/>" instead of only "s" char.
what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, but you need to output `character[0]`:

```
printf("%c", character[0]);
```

You should drop the address operator in front of `character`, though, as `sscanf()` expects an argument of type `char *` and not `char (*)[1]`:

```
sscanf(data, "<param value=%c/>", character);
```

Answer (score 0):

`char character[1]` could be replaced by `char character`, fixing your bug at the same time.

If you want to keep `character` as an array, you must use `&character[0]` or `character` as `sscanf` argument, and `character[0]` as `printf` argument.

Comment: If I use "char character" and then "&character" in the sscanf then I get an exception from the strtok(data, character). That I'm try to use that function without casting a pointer to an int. which I don't get why?

Comment: You have one character. Why are you trying to split it up?